# Primes p such that p | ((p-1)/2)! + 1

Tags: nt.number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Primes P such that ((P-1)/2)!=1 mod P](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16141/primes-p-such-that-p-1-21-mod-p)

Motivation comes from comments in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30101/composite-pairs-of-the-form-n-1-and-n1), and it is interesting in its own right. These primes are sequence [A055939](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A055939) in OEIS.

So, which primes $p$ satisfy $p\\ |\\ (\frac{p-1}{2})! + 1$?

If my calculations (in sage) are correct, the following is true for all primes under 100,000. For $p > 3$:
$$p\\ |\\ (\frac{p-1}{2})! + 1 \iff h(\sqrt{-p})=1 \mod{4}$$

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16141/primes-p-such-that-p-1-21-mod-p . Sorry Dror---I could have told you that earlier.

Comment: Perhaps it's time for the OEIS entry to be updated.

Comment: Dror, does this mean that the Cohen-Lenstra Heuristics are relevant to my question?

Comment: Well, in a way. 1. From what I remember, in the original paper by Cohen and Lenstra there is no mention of congruences on the class number. 2. You also need the truth of the first Hardy-Littewood conjecture to pairs $(n, 2n-3)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this follows from the analytic class number formula.
See
http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/97/sign .

**Added** I have now found a reference. This is a theorem of Mordell:

L. J. Mordell, 
The congruence $(p - 1/2)! \equiv \pm 1 (\operatorname{mod} p)$,
*American Mathematical Monthly*, **68** (1961), 145-146.
http://www.jstor.org/stable/2312481

Comment: Yeah but it's still a duplicate, and furthermore this reference and many other things are in the other thread. The less gets added here, the better.

Comment: Ouch Kevin, I only just noticed this....